# Is Query best for "calling" multiple columns and presenting columns in a new order?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_YT7UVHhZrBl5zGoySmcU-eZjc8hVXP-4MLP9-660X8/edit?usp=sharing) I have 2 sheets; **Schedule** with an ordinary schedule for a pupil and **Export** with headlines strutured for export to Google Calendar.

What I am trying to do is to rearrange data from Schedule to Export.

The challenge for me is to retrieve both event (mon, tue, wed, thu, fri) AND Start Time AND end Time. Am I suppose to use a Query with VLookup or Tranpose or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(Schedule!C2:G<>""; "♦"&Schedule!A2:A&"♠"&Schedule!B2:B&"♠"&Schedule!C2:G; )
 ;;99^99));;99^99); "♦")); "♠"); "select Col3 where Col1 is not null"; ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank You.